# Windows installer using makemsi cannot merge 'policy_8_0_Microsoft_VC80_DebugCRT_x86_x64.msm'

Tags: windows, installation, windows-installer

I am using makemsi's command 'Mergemodule' to include Microsoft's redistribuitable 'policy_8_0_Microsoft_VC80_DebugCRT_x86_x64.msm' to my msi.

The ppwizard preprocessor gives me error 'The underlying OLE container used to store binary data has has a key limit of 62 characters.This was exceeded by 2 character(s), the key '_MAKEMSI_Cabs.policy_8_0_Microsoft_VC80_DebugCRT_x86_x64.msm.cab'

I believe this happens because binary data is stored inside msi as OLE Stream with key created by concatenating the table name and the values of the record's primary keys using a period delimiter.The Limit for this key is 62 characters which exceeds here with '_MAKEMSI_Cabs.policy_8_0_Microsoft_VC80_DebugCRT_x86_x64.msm.cab' where '_MAKEMSI_Cabs' is the table Name and 'policy_8_0_Microsoft_VC80_DebugCRT_x86_x64.msm.cab' is value.

Can anyone please suggest a work around for this. Thanks in advance.